# how to save the date and time value in the variable as posixct

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to enter two different times manually and I want to save in the variable and would like to use it in the plot later. but I am currently getting NA in the variable E. Could someone look and describe what's the problem?

```
lab_time<-c("22.11.2021 22:45, 22.11.2021 23:25")

E<-as.POSIXct(lab_time,format='%d.%M.%y %h:%m')
```

Comment: Try `lab_time <- c("22.11.2021 22:45",  "22.11.2021 23:25")`.

Comment: You have again a typo...

Comment: yes, there was a typo mistake I corrected it and it works. thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lab_time variable is one string but they have to be separate strings.

```
lab_time <- c("22.11.2021 22:45", "22.11.2021 23:25")
```

Additionally, the format has to be "H" for hour, "M" for minute, "m" for month and "Y" for 4-digit year (Century).

Brought together:

```
as.POSIXct(lab_time, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
[1] "2021-11-22 22:45:00 CET" "2021-11-22 23:25:00 CET"
```